# Best way to make Twitter Bootstrap tabs persistent

Tags: jquery, tabs, twitter-bootstrap

What is the best way of making these tabs persist?

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

To add some context, this is for a [Ruby on Rails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) application. I'm passing an array [tab1, tab2] to my view, rendering both tabs and using the Bootstrap tab plugin to toggle their visibility.

Comment: are using any server side language like php?

Comment: using rails and the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem

Comment: can't you use a URL variable during the page refresh, and make it default using rails?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This code selects the right tab depending on the #hash and adds the right #hash when a tab is clicked. (this uses jQuery)

In CoffeeScript:

```
$(document).ready ->
    if location.hash != ''
         $('a[href="'+location.hash+'"]').tab('show')

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on 'shown', (e) ->
        location.hash = $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1)
```

Or in JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (location.hash !== '') $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
    return $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function(e) {
      return location.hash = $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks much for this answer. I made some tweaks to it in order to avoid two issues: 1) Switching tabs was adding to navigation history and 2) Scroll position was lost on back nav due to fragment navigation. https://gist.github.com/josheinstein/5586469

Comment: This will not work in bootstrap 3. Use `shown.bs.tab` instead of `shown` for the event name. [Check here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)

Comment: great answer, but if you want to avoid "jumping" of the page when you start clicking on your tabs, use this code instead of "return"

`$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
                if(history.pushState) history.pushState(null, null, '#'+$(e.target).attr('href').substr(1));
                else location.hash = '#'+$(e.target).attr('href').substr(1);
            });`

Comment: I made the Bootstrap 3 change, added it to my Rails app and it worked.   Between Rails, gems and StackOverflow I feel like I barely write any actual code anymore.

Answer (score 36):

I wanted to improve the best answer here...

Credit goes [to Sucrenoir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685968/best-way-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-persistent/10120221#10120221), but if you want to avoid jumping on the page when you change tabs, use this improved code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Show active tab on reload
    if (location.hash !== '') $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');

    // Remember the hash in the URL without jumping
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
       if(history.pushState) {
            history.pushState(null, null, '#'+$(e.target).attr('href').substr(1));
       } else {
            location.hash = '#'+$(e.target).attr('href').substr(1);
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Best answer for bootstrap 3

Comment: Copy, paste and relax. Thanks

Comment: while @Sucrenoir answer is a good one and I have used that to solve my own issue, this answer supersedes it because somehow on Sucrenoir's answer the page does not update the `#` on the first tab change. Only the first. However this code, by @dootzky *does* update the reference on the first and every tab click. Cheers

Comment: I am getting an error `TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined`   for this line `history.pushState(null, null, '#' + $(e.target).attr('href').substr(1));`

Comment: When navigating tabs, then pressing browser back button, it does not load the previously selected tab.

Answer (score 14):

Here is another way to solve the problem.

First add a line to the click event to show the hash in the address bar:

```
$('#myTab').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Add this line
  window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');

  $(this).tab('show');
})
```

Then make sure that the right tab is activated `onload` by adding this part to your document ready call.

```
if(window.location.hash){
   $('#myTab').find('a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').tab('show');
}
```

All together you can write this:

```
// Cache the ID
var navbox = $('#myTab');

// Activate tab on click
navbox.on('click', 'a', function (e) {
  var $this = $(this);

  // Prevent the ***default*** behavior
  e.preventDefault();

  // Set the hash to the address bar
  window.location.hash = $this.attr('href');

  // Activate the clicked tab
  $this.tab('show');
})

// If we have a hash in the address bar
if(window.location.hash){

  // Show right tab on load (read hash from address bar)
  navbox.find('a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').tab('show');
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this use the back and forward browser buttons??

Comment: Did you test it? It should change the history based on the changed hashes in the url. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Yes...The script changes the browser URL relevant to the tab selected but it doesn't actually change the tab itself. it still stays as the one it is on when the browser back arrow is pressed.

Comment: Ok you need to listen to the ```hashchange```event. Quick&Dirty: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/GrBzD/3/show) | [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/GrBzD/3/)

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to improve the best two answers here.. :)

Credit goes [to Sucrenoir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685968/best-way-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-persistent/10120221#10120221) [and d-wade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685968/best-way-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-persistent/21443271#21443271).

Because the history API is used in code, you can't use onchangehash (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange). This code add the functionality of back button (https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate).

```
// Show active tab on reload
if (location.hash !== '')
    $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');

// Remember the hash in the URL without jumping
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    if(history.pushState) {
        history.pushState(null, null, '#'+$(e.target).attr('href').substr(1));
    }
    else {
        location.hash = '#'+$(e.target).attr('href').substr(1);
    }
});

// Remember to back button
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

Comment: I have been having issues with the previous answers to make the hash append in the URL when a tab is shown... This answer worked perfectly out-of-the-box for me

Answer (score 2):

Tested for Bootstrap 4, minimalist (two lines) code without history push, that works on any page with nav-tabs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // Store the currently selected tab in the hash value
        $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) { location.replace($(e.target).attr("href")); });

        // Switch to the currently selected tab when loading the page
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This simply works! I just copy pasted it and that's it! (Bootstrap4)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the URL fragment (that's the part of the URL after `#`) on load using `window.location.hash`, and specifically set that tab as visible:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    $(window.location.hash).tab('show')
}
```

Comment: The hash won't be sent to the server, so not sure how i'd use this on it's own.

Comment: It won't be sent to the server as it has no need to be - the example above is javascript. For example, if you have an `a` element which sends the browser to `yoursite.com/about#company` the `#company` tab will be displayed. On refresh, the URL will be checked for a fragment, and if there is one will display the tab with the matching `id` by default.

Comment: I edited my question to remove the 'persist a refresh' as it was misleading. My real problem is that I have pagination links and when I change page in tab2 it reverts back to tab1

Answer (score 1):

Another modified version if you don't want tab clicks to be added to the history, but also don't want the page jumping up and down:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  if (location.hash !== '') {
    $('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
  }

  $("a[data-toggle='tab']").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
    var hash = $(e.target).attr("href");
    if (hash.substr(0,1) == "#") {
      var position = $(window).scrollTop();
      location.replace("#" + hash.substr(1));
      $(window).scrollTop(position);
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following code after DOM load:

```
$('a[data-toggle=tab]').on('click', function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, $(this).attr('href'));
});


if (window.location.hash) {
    $('a[data-toggle=tab][href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

However, this leads to poor UI experience, since the currently active tab will be shown first, and then it will be switched to a tab from location.hash.