# Bootstrap 3: how to link directly to a tab from another page in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink, tabs

I am building a web app with Rails 4 and Bootstrap 3.

In one of the pages, I have the following [Bootstrap tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#billing" aria-controls="billing" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card" aria-hidden="true"></span> Billing</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#expert" aria-controls="expert" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></span> Expert</a></li>
  </ul>
```

and then, the following content in these tabs:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="profile">
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="billing">
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="expert">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I hover any of these tabs, I see that the direct URL is, ie: `http://localhost:3000/account/edit#profile`, `http://localhost:3000/account/edit#billing` and `http://localhost:3000/account/edit#expert`.

However, when I try to link directly to the tab from another page, the active tab is still the first one (not the one I linked to).

Two notes:

1. I am using Bootstrap tabs "without any JavaScript", as explained [in the markdown section in the documentation](http://You%20can%20activate%20a%20tab%20or%20pill%20navigation%20without%20writing%20any%20JavaScript%20by%20simply%20specifying%20data-toggle=%22tab%22%20or%20data-toggle=%22pill%22%20on%20an%20element).
2. I would like to link to these tabs using Rails `link_to` helper.

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: You'd like the a link_to helper to link to only one of the tabs right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I would like. This link to be more specific: `http://localhost:3000/account/edit#expert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to accomplish what you're after without throwing some javascript into the mix, as the tabs are meant for intrapage nagivation, not interpage navigation.  Additionally, the `href` tags aren't even required on those tabs, as it's the `data-toggle` attribute which controls which tab pane to present.

If adding a small javascript snippet is a viable option, this will switch to the appropriate tab when the page is navigated to.

```
hash = window.location.hash
$("a[href=#{hash}]").click()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tL7sutnt/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can definitely use some JS, I just specified in my question that I was not because most other answers I had found on my own were in cases where tabs were implemented with JS. If I want to go with your solution, where do you recommend to include this JS code: in the view with <script></script> tags, in a dedicated .coffee file or somewhere else?

Comment: Where possible, it would be best to place javascript (or in this case, coffeescript) in the dedicated file whose name matches that of the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the active tab in the view

```
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> Profile</a></li>
```

which is going to take precedence.

If you want this to work, you need to add the active class to whatever tab is being referenced in the url anchor (#expert, in your case)

See [this post if you need code reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215296/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-go-to-specific-tab-on-page-load)

***EDIT:
Since you aren't using js, use the answer at the bottom that dynamically determines the active tab by parsing the request