# Why the anchor does not appear in the url after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have such HTML:

```
<div class="parrent pull-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="analistic-01">TAB1</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="analistic-02">TAB2</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" class="analistic-03">TAB3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is navigation for tabs. But it behaves something different: when I click on the link (for example: `<a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="analistic-01">TAB1</a>`) - required tab is displayed. But there is not the anchor in url(`#tab1` or `#tab2` or `#tab3)`. But I need it...

I am some new in fronted and I use ready template. So there are such frameworks:

```
jquery.js, bootstrap.min.js, js/jquery.isotope.min.js
```

What should I do??

Comment: _But I need it..._ may be there are better ways of doing it if you could explain more about your requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to make twitter bootstrap tabs persistent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685968/best-way-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-persistent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685968/best-way-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-persistent) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131273/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-url-doesnt-change) (if you are using bootstrap for tabs managing).

Comment: Please don't answer questions with links to other questions. Instead, click "close" > "duplicate of" > and paste the link to the duplicate uestion : )

Comment: @DelightedD0D Thank you :)